# Add a Selector from a UITableViewCell class to the UITableViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying do design my own UITableViewCell to include a Stepper in the AccessoryView. Therefore, I would like to add selector so that the ViewController would handle the behaviour of the value being changed. (The UITableViewCell should only be responsible to display the result in its label)

Currently, I'm able to modify the label's text by using addTarget to the UITableViewCell class, but when I add a target to the UITableViewController class, I get the following error:

```
2018-10-08 20:04:39.157912-0400 MyProject[1003:45273] -[MyProject expansionSelectionValueDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa88700fc00
2018-10-08 20:04:39.167219-0400 MyProject[1003:45273] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyProject.PlayerSelectionCell expansionSelectionValueDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa88700fc00'
```

I'm using X-Code 10 and Swift 4 to develop an iOS 12 application.

Here's the code to the UITableViewCell :

```
class PlayerSelectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    @objc func stepperValueDidChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        textLabel?.text = "\(newValue) Players"
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let stepper = UIStepper()
        stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SetupViewController.expansionSelectionValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.accessoryView = stepper
    }
}
```

Here's the code to my UITableViewController

```
class SetupViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var setupTableView: UITableView!

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "Expansions"
        case 1:
            return "Players"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return Expansions.allCases.count
        case 1:
            return 3
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Expansion Selection", for: indexPath) as? ExpansionCell ?? ExpansionCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = Expansions.allCases[indexPath.row].rawValue
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Player Selection", for: indexPath) as? PlayerSelectionCell ?? PlayerSelectionCell()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Player Detail", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell ?? PlayerCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Player \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
        }
    }

    @objc func playerCountValueDidChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        print("Value : \(sender.value)")
    }

    @objc func expansionSelectionValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print("Value : \(sender.isOn)")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all look like you're trying to add a Target to a UIStepper called expansionSelectionValueDidChange, but the sender in this method is fot a UISwitch. First try change **expansionSelectionValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch)** to **expansionSelectionValueDidChange(_ sender: UIStepper)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In alternative to the accepted solution:

Depending on case you can try use delegate instead action/target

```
//Declare a delegate for the cell
protocol PlayerSelectionCellDelegate : class {
    func playerSelectionCell(_ cell:PlayerSelectionCell, didChangeValue:Double)
    func playerSelectionCell(_ cell:PlayerSelectionCell, expansionSelectionValueDidChange:Bool)
}

class PlayerSelectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate : PlayerSelectionCellDelegate?        //Set a weak var to allocate the delegate

    @objc func stepperValueDidChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        delegate?.playerSelectionCell(self, didChangeValue: sender.value)
    }

    @objc func expansionSelectionValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.playerSelectionCell(self, expansionSelectionValueDidChange: sender.isOn)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let stepper = UIStepper()
        stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)

        //This line should be reference to the UISwitch Action
        selectionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expansionSelectionValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
        self.accessoryView = stepper
    }
}
```

In the ViewController you change the code to get in conformity to the delegate and set the ViewController as delegated to cell

```
class SetupViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var setupTableView: UITableView!

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "Expansions"
        case 1:
            return "Players"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return Expansions.allCases.count
        case 1:
            return 3
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Expansion Selection", for: indexPath) as? ExpansionCell ?? ExpansionCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = Expansions.allCases[indexPath.row].rawValue
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Player Selection", for: indexPath) as? PlayerSelectionCell ?? PlayerSelectionCell()
            cell.delegate = self            //Set the ViewController to be delegated by cell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Player Detail", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell ?? PlayerCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Player \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //Remove the actions and implements the delegate methods
    func playerSelectionCell(_ cell: PlayerSelectionCell, didChangeValue players: Double) {
        print("Value Players: \(players)")
    }

    func playerSelectionCell(_ cell: PlayerSelectionCell, expansionSelectionValueDidChange selected: Bool) {
        print("Value Selected: \(selected)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Considering this option allows me to customize the parameters to my needs (instead of just a sender), I believe this may be the better option! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is that the `addTarget(_ target, ...)` method invokes the selector on `target`. Even if you specify it like you did with full path.

What you can try is to set target to `nil` and it should work then if the documentation is right:

> The target object—that is, the object whose action method is called. If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the message to that object.

And if that doesn't help, specifying the target exactly should solve it. You will just have to pass a reference to the controller.

Comment: Using nil solved the problem, but I'd like to know how to specify the target exactly, should the problem arise again!

Thank you!

Comment: That is specific to each case. Here I would go the way proposed by @dede.exe Delegation pattern is usual way of doing this on iOS.